# Ubuntu 16.04 Multiple Network Adapters, Same Network

Tags: networking, gateway, ip-address

I need to configure a gateway PC working with Ubuntu 16.04 so that multiple LAN adapters (eth0,eht1,wlan0) communicate within one same network addressing scheme.

How can such a configuration be made in Ubuntu 16.04?

[image: Example of whats needed]

Comment: You could do something like this using subnets smaller than class 'c', but why?  Why do you need to have the different network cards attached to different devices, on the same network?  Who not have them on different subnets, and configure GW as a router between the subnets, and allow the laptop to use GW as a router to connect to the different devices?  This is not truly a question about Ubuntu, but a question about how to configure network topology.

Comment: @CharlesGreen It's still on topic if they want to create it in an Ubuntu environment.

Comment: From a purely networking theory, this is a very painful attempt to set things up.  You would have to set up `wlan0` to be its own wifi hotspot, among other things, and that is dependent on the specific type of infrastructure you have.  You mention that this is a Dell Edge Gateway, they should already have the utilities installed to make this work; did you wipe it and put Ubuntu on it, or something?

Comment: @ThomasWard I think the only part of this which would be on-topic for this is the fact that they would like to do this with Ubuntu, rather than a dedicated router box or network switch.  There is a deeper underlying problem that the OP would need to know and understand the use of network masks to perform this as illustrated, as opposed to simply using three separate class 'c' networks (192.168.101.x, 192.68.102.x, and 192.168.103.x for example)

Comment: wlan0 is already working as an AP.

Comment: Most of what you are looking for can be found in [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router)  There are remaining questions that would like to be answered:  Should 'device 1' and 'device 2' be denied access to the internet?  My point about network masks is that if you dedicate a class 'c' network to each device, you will have less homework to do in your configuration.

Comment: wlan0 is already working as an AP.

By default each adapter publishes a new network:
wlan0 10.42.0.x
eth0 10.42.1.x
eth1 10.42.2.x

The problem is that the devices are quite "special" and hard to reconfigure. They come with addresses 192.168.100.10 and 192.168.100.11